# Study guide for GCP Certified System Architect

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

Wondering is anyone had any good techniques, book recommendations. video links or Labs which might be useful for anyone looking to study and take the **Google Cloud Certified System Architect exam**  ?

I've already taken a look at these , which seemed quite good:

## Prerequisites:

- https://google.qwiklabs.com/quests/24
- https://google.qwiklabs.com/quests/36
- https://google.qwiklabs.com/quests/38
- https://google.qwiklabs.com/quests/45
- https://www.qwiklabs.com/quests/47

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Professional Cloud Architect - you can find plenty of resources on the [Awesome GCP Certifications](https://github.com/ddneves/awesome-gcp-certifications) repository. The [Coursera Google Cloud](https://www.coursera.org/googlecloud) specializations and courses are also a good thing to start with.